# How to run a longrunning batch job on startup of tomcat server?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-batch

I'm launching a `spring-batch` job on application start using

`spring.batch.job.names=MyJob`

```
@Configuration
public class MyJob {
    @Bean
    public Job testJob() throws IOException {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get(MyJob.class.getSimpleName())
                .start(import())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this somehow delays the `tomcat` server startup. The job has a runtime of several minutes, thus I'm getting the following error:

> Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45
>   seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout
>   in the server editor.

Question: how can I run this job without preventing tomcat to start up? Eg running the job async?

Comment: Depending on your current spring-batch config there are different ways to make this work. Could you post what you have right now?

Comment: It's just a simple job class, and as written the configured application.properties to launch the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include a [ServletContextListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

Put your code in the [contextInitialized](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent)) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@Scheduled`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) annotation configured with a [`fixedDelay`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#fixedDelay--).

See the [Task Execution and Scheduling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) in the reference for more information.

I ended up using this solution to launch a cache warm up just at startup:

```
private boolean isFirstTime = true;

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000)
protected void refreshCachesStartup(){
    if(isFirstTime){
        // your code

        isFirstTime = false;
    }
}
```

EDIT: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406713/how-to-conditionally-enable-or-disable-scheduled-jobs-in-spring) question for a more specific view on the argument.

Comment: But a `fixedDelay`would execute periodically. I only want to run the job on startup.

Comment: Hm that feels like a hack. I could as well define a very very long fixedDelay period, but maybe there is a more elegant solution to this...

Comment: AFAIK there is no built-in way to do that. You may use Spring Boot's [@ConditionalXXX](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html) annotations (or implement your own) but the base idea stay the same.