# @Scheduled without specific date

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduler

I wrote a scheduler

```
@Documented
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 0 * * *")
public @interface DeleteAndCopy{

}
```

What means every midnight. The process takes about 4 hours. (0am-4am)

Now there is a maintainance day on 28.07.2017 at 1:00 pm.

I decided to not copy data at this date to not have an unexpected state. How to exclude this date from the execution?

Comment: @Zeromus Is there something like an @NonScheduled-Annotation? Or a Incode-suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron doesnt support exclusion.
Fastest i could come up with is a double @scheduled annotation like this

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * 1-6,8-12 *")  //every month except 7
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 1-27,29-31 7 *") //every day of month 7 except 28
```

(tried first with minutes with something like this and it seems to work for me

```
@Scheduled(cron = "00 1-20,25-59 * * * *") //every minute except 21,22,23,24 for every hour
@Scheduled(cron = "00 21 10 * * *") //minute 21 for 10 am (dunno your timezone)
```

)

Definitely not elegant though

Comment: A cruel kind of ingenious!

Answer (score 0):

The cron syntax doesn't seem to support exclusion of a specific date. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128657/105305) from the Unix and Linux StackExchange site:

> Standard cron syntax is quite simple, it does not support exclusions. In some cases it is possible to create a list of several/many cron entries to implement such logic, but that tends be tedious and hard to understand or maintain; this approach is not applicable in your case though (not least because standard cron has no notion of the calendar year).

I can think about a couple of a few solutions for your problem:

- Make the logic executed by the timer conditional, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18406954/1421925). You could have a boolean property which determines whether the logic should execute or not. The timer will unfortunately still trigger, but you can use the property to not execute its logic.
- A little more sophisticated solution would be the same as above, but keep a list of dates for which to disable the execution.
- Even simpler, but much less sophisticated, add the exclusion of the date directly to the code: `if (!LocalDate.now().equals(LocalDate.of(2017, 7, 28)))`. Depending on the type of application, this might be acceptable.
- A fourth option would be to programatically create the scheduler. You could use [`HolidayCalendar`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/impl/calendar/HolidayCalendar.html) from the Quartz API to exclude the date. It has a method [`addExcludedDate(Date date)`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/impl/calendar/HolidayCalendar.html#addExcludedDate(java.util.Date)) which does exactly what you want. A full example, using Spring, is available in [this preview of an E-book](https://books.google.se/books?id=q2PIjAJoXsAC&pg=PA507&lpg=PA507&dq=exclude%20dates%20spring%20scheduled&source=bl&ots=PUFrU2A0CS&sig=rR_hoL8gvTBY_JE80Mob4l0DjqY&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkqrDPrOLTAhUCCCwKHWh8Bq8Q6AEITjAF#v=onepage&q=exclude%20dates%20spring%20scheduled&f=false). I am not sure if I am allow to copy the example, so I am only posting the link.

Answer (score 0):

By principle a CMMS can be asked for planed Maintainance scopes in-code.