# How to handle misfire triggers in Quartz Scheduler?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled, quartz

I have a Quartz Scheduler. If I run the scheduler after maintenance window or so, it should not run the misfire triggers older than 15 minutes. How can I control this?

Is there any property or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conditionally enable or disable scheduled jobs in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406713/how-to-conditionally-enable-or-disable-scheduled-jobs-in-spring)

Comment: No, I am talking about shutting down the scheduler. Once I up the schedule again it should not run misfire triggers prior to min mins.

Comment: So after restarting the server, u don't want to misfire the triggers before the actual time. means after the restart, triggers have to work only at a scheduled time?

Comment: Yes @sudhakar. The scheduler should not run the misfire triggers prior to 15 mins or so.

Comment: then you can use the above mentioned post and modify the variable as per your requirement - as for your, make it true so it check for the 15 mins time frame on your system restart and false afterwards