# Is it possible to assign @Scheduled with a period representing "never" (in Spring)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I'm investigating using [@Scheduled](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) at a fixed rate where in some *configurable* circumstances the scheduled job should never be run.

The documentation doesn't mention this but the default values for `fixedDelay()` and `fixedDelayString()` are `-1` and `""` respectively. Can these be used to reliably ensure that the scheduled method doesn't fire?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not. When you set the `fixedDelay` attribute to `-1` or attempt use `@Scheduled` without specifying a valid value for any of its attributes, Spring will complain that no attribute is set:

> Exactly one of the `'cron'`, `'fixedDelay(String)'`, or `'fixedRate(String)'` attributes is required

You can verify this behavior by going through the source code of [`ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#processScheduled`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L267).

It contains logic like:

```
boolean processScheduled = false;

// ...

if (fixedRate >= 0) {
    Assert.isTrue(!processedSchedule, errorMessage);
    processedSchedule = true;
    this.registrar.addFixedRateTask(new IntervalTask(runnable, fixedRate, initialDelay));
}

// ...

Assert.isTrue(processedSchedule, errorMessage);
```

Take a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18406713/1291150) for some options for conditionally disabling `@Scheduled`.

Comment: Oh, that's a shame - thanks for looking into it. I guess one  possible workaround not mentioned in the post you linked might be to set extremely high (i.e. the max `long`) values for `initialDelay` and `fixedDelay` so they are never actually reached. This may work in practice but just seems a bit wrong to have to resort to this and a shame that Spring didn't provide a "never" option.

Comment: @SteveChambers Yes, that seems like a bit of a hack. Plus if you were to retrieve the value from configuration and set it using `fixedDelayStr`, it would be parsed using `Integer.parseInt` not `Long.parseLong`, so setting it to max value of long would fail :) ... I will report it later on Spring JIRA.

Comment: Oh dear, it seems `fixedDelayStr` is out of the question for this method then as the max integer is 2147483647, which (if my Google-assisted calculations are correct) in milliseconds equates to just 3 and a half weeks - bit different to the 292471208 years I think a `long` would allow!

Comment: @SteveChambers Edit: the parsing seems to be already fixed (at least in master, probably in 4.2 too). However the current Spring version I'm using (4.1.7) still has this problem.

Comment: Thanks @Bohuslav. Unfortunately we're using 4.17 too - might have to see if it's possible to migrate...

Comment: Looks like without the upgrade another option would be a cron expression. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835221#13938099) relates to Quartz but would expect something simple like `0 0 0 1 1 ? 2099` should do the job (and am willing to take the hit on the "year 2099 bug"!)

Comment: Oh dear, again maybe not - need milliseconds precision, which unfortunately cron doesn't seem to provide.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in spring docs, you can specify `"-"` to disable the triggering of the task:

> CRON_DISABLED: A special cron expression value that indicates a disabled trigger:
> `"-"`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#CRON_DISABLED