# How to disable @Scheduled method via properties file?

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring scheduled method that is periodically run:

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "${spring.cron.expression}")
public void demonJob() { ... }
```

The cron expression is successfully read from the `application.properties`:

```
spring.cron.expression=0 0 * * * *
```

Now, I want to deploy my application to a special environment on which this particular scheduled method is not supposed to run. If I leave the cron property empty like this...

```
spring.cron.expression=
```

... I get the following exception:

```
Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'demonJob': Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 0 in "")
```

How can I disable the Scheduled method elegantly, ideally only by providing a different setting in `application.properties`?

Comment: If you ever want to go this way, this topic is about "never executing cron expressions" : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835221/quartz-cron-expression-that-will-never-execute

Comment: @Berger but that question deals with quartz cron expressions which seem more flexible than spring cron expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Empty string is an incorrect cron expression. If you want to disable scheduler in particular condition just use `@Profile` annotation or if you have to operate on property use `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation from Spring Boot.

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.cron", name = "expression")
public class MyScheduler {
   @Scheduled(cron = "${spring.cron.expression}")
   public void demonJob() throws .. { .. }
}
```

Comment: ConditionalOnProperty seems like a cool solution - unfortunately this is not a Spring Boot Project. The Profile solution would require that we add all profiles that want the scheduler, but we much rather would disable it only for one specific profile.

Comment: You can very simply implement @ConditionalOnProperty on your own. It's Conditional class with 5 lines

Answer (score 12):

As of Spring 5.1.0, the special cron value "-" can be used with the [`@Scheduled`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--) annotation to disable the cron trigger.

> The special value "-" indicates a disabled cron trigger, primarily meant for externally specified values resolved by a ${...} placeholder.

For your specific example, you merely need to set the `spring.cron.expression` variable to this value.  If this is a Spring Boot project, you can use one of the many [externalized configuration options available](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for this purpose, including:

- Command line argument
- Java System property
- OS environment variable
- Profile-specific application property for a profile used specifically for that environment

If this is not a Spring Boot project, you can still specify this property, though the mechanism to do so is going to be less standard and more project specific.

Comment: Ooof. Big save here... Would upvote several times. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I could give another approach. Just redefine applicatino cron expression in any way to set unreachable time period. E.g. `spring.cron.expression=1 1 1 1 1 ?` (this is I use in my code and it is enough for me).

Profit of this approach is that you do not have to do any additional changes in the code.

Comment: Isn't your example to be executed Jan 1st at 1:01:01? That doesn't look like "never". Or do you assume to change the schedule right before that date to avoid execution? Could you please explain in more details?

Comment: You're right. I just wanted to set unreachable scheduler. This expression works for my code (yes, I think it will be run one once per year). But I wanted to give an approach to solve this problem (you could set one time moment in two years e.g.)

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Solution to your Question**

1. Configure your properties file based on the environment
2. Configure your ApplicationContext according to your environment profile.
3. Use Environment Specific CRON Entries.
4. Please check this [link](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-using-environment-specific-cron-expressions-with-the-scheduled-annotation/) which may help you.