# JdbcPollingChannelAdapter: Poll database manually only

Tags: spring-integration

I have a JdbcPollingChannelAdapter which reads data via JDBC. I want to make it poll manually (using a commandChannel). It should never poll automatically, and it should run immediately when I trigger a manual poll.

Below I am using a poller which runs every 24 hours to get the channel running at all. I cannot use a cronExpression that never fires as in [Quartz: Cron expression that will never execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835221/quartz-cron-expression-that-will-never-execute) since Pollers.cronExpression() takes no year.

```
@Bean
public MessageSource<Object> jdbcMessageSource() {
    return new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(this.dataSource, "SELECT...");
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jdbcFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(jdbcMessageSource(),
                    spec -> spec.poller(
                        Pollers.fixedRate(24, TimeUnit.HOURS)))
            .handle(System.out::println)
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you go right way about `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` and `commandChannel`, but you don't have configure `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` as you do with that `IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource()`.

What you need is really the `jdbcMessageSource()`, but to poll it manually you should configure command-based flow:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jdbcFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("commandChannel")
            .handle(jdbcMessageSource(), "receive")
            .handle(System.out::println)
            .get();
}
```

Exactly that `receive()` is called from the `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` on the timing basis.