# How to set up cron jobs can not run any time?

Tags: spring, design-patterns, schedule

i set up cron jobs run in :

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.schedule.pattern}", zone = "Asia/Singapore")
```

And in file config :

```
cron.schedule.pattern=*/40 * 7-23 * * *
```

how to change pattern to `@Schedule` can not run instead of comment line `@Schedule`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835221/quartz-cron-expression-that-will-never-execute

Comment: @DavideCavestro : Thanks, just set to run in 3000 years

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quartz: Cron expression that will never execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835221/quartz-cron-expression-that-will-never-execute)