# Spring Cron scheduler “disable pattern”

Tags: spring, cron, scheduled-tasks

My application loads some cron patterns from a properties file. I'm using the `@Scheduled` annotation like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${config.cronExpression:0 0 11,23 * * *}")
```

Now I want to disable some tasks and the easiest solution would be to enter a cron pattern which will never run.
In order to do this, I thought about using a cron expression that only executes at a specific day in the past.
But unfortunately the Spring cron expressions don't allow to add a year or a date in the past.

Is there any pattern that will never run?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but I know we localy use the cron-expression 'none' successfully. But this might be a hack... Other people suggest using February 31th, or December 31th 2099... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324306/cron-job-that-will-never-execute http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835221/quartz-cron-expression-that-will-never-execute/13938099#13938099

Answer (score 86, accepted):

As of Spring 5.1.0 the `@Scheduled` annotation can accept `"-"` as the cron expression to disable the cron trigger.

Per the [Javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.5/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--):

> The special value [`"-"`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.5/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#CRON_DISABLED) indicates a disabled cron trigger, primarily meant for externally specified values resolved by a `${...}` placeholder.

Comment: Using this special value in a properties yml means you need to include the quotes. So, it's really
`cron-expression: "-"`

Answer (score 8):

If it was a **cron** expression (NOT spring scheduler), you could have used below which makes the cron run on 2099

```
59 59 23 31 12 ? 2099
```

But spring scheduler does not take a year as input. This is what I have found to defer it for some extended period. Below will run on 29 Feb which will be a leap year.

```
0 0 0 29 2 ?
```

Comment: This is the better option if the value is being read from an external file and a code change is not desired

Answer (score 6):

If you're stuck pre Spring 5.1.0 (SpringBoot < 2.1), your only option may be to disable the bean/service with the `@Scheduled` method altogether, for example by using a `@ConditionalOnProperty("my.scheduleproperty.active")` annotation and not setting the property (or setting it to false)