# Can I make my CodePipeline only executed when triggered manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I have a CodePipeline setup. But now I want to only have my Pipeline run when I trigger it manually, is that possible?

Comment: wondering a similar thing, did the answer below work for you?

Comment: @fuzzi, I believe thats possible, tho for me, I added an approval step. Btw, now you can disable transitions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/transitions.html

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

Set up a regular pipeline with **Github webhook** set.
This will create and register an internal aws webhook.
Then simply deregister and remove the webhooks [like it is written in the aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-webhooks-delete.html) via aws-cli.

Adjust the following to your region, mine is us-east-2:

Find out the name of the webhook:

```sh
aws codepipeline list-webhooks
```

De-register:

```sh
aws codepipeline deregister-webhook-with-third-party --webhook-name <webhook-name>
```

Delete:

```sh
aws codepipeline delete-webhook --name <webhook-name>
```

Note:
It's necessary to have the source step configured to use the **Github webhook**.

Now you can trigger your pipeline manually via AWS Console or via aws-cli with:

```sh
aws codepipeline start-pipeline-execution --name <pipeline-name>
```

Comment: Yea, this worked, like a charm! It should be the correct answer!. Just the `--endpoint-url` and `--region` are not necessary, they don't exist in the new API.
`aws codepipeline list-webhooks` is enough. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need configure your CodePipeline to be triggered by CloudWatch event. Once you've done that, an event rule under CloudWatch named "codepipeline-{repository_name}" will be created.

Disabling this rule will stop CodePipeline from been triggered by CodeCommit. When you need a build, just click 'Release Change' button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CloudWatch Events, to never trigger your pipeline:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-trigger-source-schedule-console.html

Set up a cronjob that [will never execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324306/cron-job-that-will-never-execute), and then you can manually trigger the pipeline whenever you want by clicking on the 'Release change' button.
I haven't tested, but I think it should work.

Comment: Can I still poll from my git repository with this method?