# scheduled cron expression that never runs

Tags: spring-boot, cron

What I tried:

```
 @Scheduled(cron="* * * 08 04 2099")
```

I want cron expression that never executes.can any one help me with the expression.

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: If you want cron not to execute then why would you write one?

Comment: I want to set cron based on value from database(only if value matches with database value then cron should execute else the cron should not execute)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cron job that will never execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324306/cron-job-that-will-never-execute)

Comment: You need to have cron but the operation can be executed based on database condition.

Comment: on spring boot's cron interpreter this causes Invalid cron expression "0 0 5 31 2 *" led to runaway search for next trigger

Comment: yes -@MuhammadWaqasDilawar

Comment: How often do you need this cron job to run?

Comment: Already said, it gets executed based on database condition

Comment: CRON is bound to time and condition is bound to database, so tried to give you sample in answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217868/discussion-between-muhammad-waqas-dilawar-and-bollam-rohith).

Comment: If you got your answer then kindly accept my answer.

Comment: @bollam_rohith Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cron will run every minute and task will be bound with condition.
If you need different cron job then you can generate using this [website](http://www.cronmaker.com/?8).

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *")
protected void performTask() {
    if (condition)//if value matches with database value
    {
        //perform the task
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression}")

cron.expression=-
```

This works from Spring 5.1.

See the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.5/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--).